# How to do multiple queries in Spring Batch (specifically use LAST_INSERT_ID())

Tags: mysql, spring, csv, spring-batch

I am trying to write a Spring Batch Starter job that reads a CSV file and inserts the records into a MySQL DB. When it begins I want to save the start time in a tracking table, and when it ends, the end time in that same table. The table structure is like:

```
TRACKING : id, start_time, end_time

DATA: id, product, version, server, fk_trk_id
```

I am unable to find an example project that does such a thing. I believe this needs to be a Spring Batch Starter project that can handle multiple queries. i.e.

// insert start time

```
1. INSERT INTO tracking (start_time) VALUES (NOW(6));
```

// get last inserted id for foreign key

```
2. SET @last_id_in_tracking = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

// read from CSV and insert data into 'data' DB table

```
3. INSERT INTO data (product, version, server, fk_trk_id) VALUES (mysql, 5.1.42, Server1, @last_id_in_tracking);
4. INSERT INTO data (product, version, server, fk_trk_id) VALUES (linux, 7.0, Server2, @last_id_in_tracking);
5. INSERT INTO data (product, version, server, fk_trk_id) VALUES (java, 8.0, Server3, @last_id_in_tracking);
```

// insert end time

```
6. UPDATE tracking SET end_time = NOW(6) WHERE fk_trk_id = @last_id_in_table1;
```

I'd like sample code and explanation on how to use those queries to multiple tables in the same Spring Batch Starter job.

### start of edit section - additional question

I do have an additional question. In my entities I have them set-up to represent the relationships with annotations (i.e @ManyToOne, @JoinColumn)...

In your code, how would I get the trackingId from a referenced object? Let me explain:

My Code (Data.java):

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Tracking tracking;
```

Your code (Data.java):

```
@Column(name = "fk_trk_id")
private Long fkTrkId;
```

Your code (JobConfig.java):

```
final Data data = new Data();
data.setFkTrkId(trackingId);
```

How do I set the id with "setFkTrkId" when the relationship in my Entity is an object?

### end of edit section - additional question

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example app that does what you're asking.  Please see the README for details.

https://github.com/joechev/examples/tree/master/csv-reader-db-writer

Comment: Thank you Joe! I couldn't have had a better solution to my challenge. Thank you for the time spent on putting this code together.

Comment: I added a question to my original question. Can you also help in that regard?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a project for you as an example. Please refer to https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2018/02/25/spring-batch-mysql-reader-writer-processor-listener/

This example simply has a Reader/Processor/Writer. The reader will read a CSV file and then process something and then write to database.

And we have a listener to capture StartJob and EndJob. For Start Job, we will insert an entry to DB and then return a generatedId. We will pass the same ID to writer when we stored entries.

Note: I'm sorry I'm reused an example I have already. So it may not match 100% as your question but technically it should be the same.

Thanks,
Nghia